# Access DOM from a template

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Is it possible to access DOM elements from an Angular2 template ?
If not, is there a way to achieve that ?
I want to be able to access some DOM element in my template and modify it after the HTML load (load event).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

Comment: My main goal here is to be able to execute javascript code that accesses the DOM from within a template. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, inject ElementRef in your constructor and use the nativeElement property.  See the second answer in link above.